# SonarQube integration in TeamCity for .NET C# projecs

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, teamcity

I'm facig some issues with SonarQube integration in TeamCity with MSBuild.

Basically our nightly build using SonarQube is split into 5 steps:

1 - SonarQube Initialization

```
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin 
/k:"tsmm-%sonar.project%" 
/n:"%sonar.project%" 
/v:"%sonar.project.version%" 
/d:sonar.host.url="%sonar.host.url%" 
/d:sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths="coverage-report.html" 
/d:sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths="nunit-results.xml" 
/d:sonar.verbose=true 
/d:sonar.jdbc.username="%sonar.jdbc.username%" 
/d:sonar.jdbc.password="%sonar.jdbc.password%" 
/d:sonar.jdbc.url="%sonar.jdbc.url%"
```

2 - Muggets restauration

3 - MSBuild

4 - Tests via NUnit

5 - Result publication to SonarQube

```
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end 
/d:sonar.scm.disabled=true
/d:sonar.jdbc.username="%sonar.jdbc.username%" 
/d:sonar.jdbc.password="%sonar.jdbc.password%"
```

When the TeamCity is running the build definition above, everything is going fine until it reach the step no. 5 as stated in the build log:

```
Step 5/5: Publish to SonarQube (Command Line)
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
...
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: SCM URL should be provided. Please review "sonar.scm.url" parameter (or the <scm> section of pom.xml if you are using Maven).
```

I went through different resources including the official one there: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild

But could not manage to find out any proper explanation, I also tried to disable the scm support as mentioned on that page: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SCM+support
by adding `/d:sonar.scm.disabled=true` to the step 1 but it does not change anything.

Comment: What kind of SonarQube plugins do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The sonar.jdbc.* properties are only for older versions of SonarQube and if you are on a newer than 5.4, you should not set them.

To authenticate to SonarQube you need to use the sonar.login and sonar.password properties, as described in the article below:
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+the+Command+Line#FromtheCommandLine-Analyzeaproject

In all cases, if you have older SonarQube, I would strongly recommend upgrading to the LTS (long term support) version:
https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/